# SQL Index Unico

Tags: sql-server, índices

estou com uma dúvida no SQL Server.
Eu tenho a seguinte tabela, ID (integer Key), Nome (nvachar), CPF (nvachar, com index unico).

Se eu faço um inserto com o CPF que já existe, o SQL retorna com erro e isto está OK.
Agora se eu faço o insert e dá sucesso, o que eu reparei é que a coluna de ID dá um salto e não fica na sequência.

```
|   ID   |    Nome    |    CPF    |
|   1    |    João    |    1234   |
|   2    |    Pedro   |    1235   |
|   3    |    Judas   |    1236   |
|   5    |    João A  |    12347  |
```

Pelo que eu entendi, quando eu fiz a tentativa de inserção e deu erro, o próprio SQL inseriu e depois deletou o registro, por isso o próximo ID é 5 e não 4.
Existe alguma forma de isto não ocorrer? Ou a melhor forma de tratar mesmo é verificar antes de inserir?

Obrigado

Comment: Presumindo que seu campo `id` seja do tipo auto-incremento então este é o comportamento esperado, pode sim haver "buracos" na sequência.

Comment: Caso precise manter a ordem. É interessante verificar na aplicação. Validar se o usuário poderá ou não ser inserido. Embora o banco não permita.

Answer (score 2):

O seu campo ID deve ser `IDENTITY`.
Cada vez que vai ser feita uma operação, a "semente" que gera o próximo valor, fornece um valor antes de executar a operação, afinal, precisa ter isso para fazer (ou tentar) o `INSERT`, e por razões de concorrência (outra transação pode "pedir" o próximo ID antes de terminar a operação de `INSERT` que obteve o ID anterior), uma vez fornecido um ID, esse é considerado usado, e se der erro ele é perdido.

Da documetação do MSDN:

> **Reutilização de valores** – para determinada propriedade de identidade com semente/incremento específico, os valores de identidade
> não são reutilizados pelo mecanismo. Se uma instrução de inserção
> específica falhar ou se a instrução de inserção for revertida, os
> valores de identidade consumidos serão perdidos e não serão gerados
> novamente. Isso pode resultar em intervalos quando os valores de
> identidade subsequentes são gerados.

Fonte: [https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15)